# jq not accepting raw input

Tags: bash, jq

I'm running a bash script that would format an HTML entry, which, in turn, would be used as input for a JSON file. Below is the formatted HTML input which returns the expected output.

RAW

```
template='"''<h3><span style=\''"text-decoration: underline;\''"><strong><em>Build Execute Summary</em></strong></span></h3><p>&nbsp;</p><table style=\''"border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; height: 162px;\''" border=\''"1\''"><tbody><tr style=\''"height: 18px;\''"><td style=\''"width: 33.7887%; height: 18px; text-align: center;\''"><strong>Result</strong></td><td style=\''"width: 66.2113%; height: 18px; text-align: center;\''">'$notif_result'</td></tr><tr style=\''"height: 18px;\''"><td style=\''"width: 33.7887%; height: 18px; text-align: center;\''"><strong>Infra Type</strong></td><td style=\''"width: 66.2113%; height: 18px; text-align: center;\''">internal</td></tr><tr style=\''"height: 18px;\''"><td style=\''"width: 33.7887%; text-align: center; height: 18px;\''"><strong>Environment</strong></td><td style=\''"width: 66.2113%; text-align: center; height: 18px;\''">'$environment'</td></tr><tr style=\''"height: 18px;\''"><td style=\''"width: 33.7887%; text-align: center; height: 18px;\''"><strong>Application Name</strong></td><td style=\''"width: 66.2113%; text-align: center; height: 18px;\''">'$application'</td></tr><tr style=\''"height: 18px;\''"><td style=\''"width: 33.7887%; height: 18px; text-align: center;\''"><strong>Build Name</strong></td><td style=\''"width: 66.2113%; height: 18px; text-align: center;\''">'$region-$application-$environment-$notif_runnum'</td></tr><tr style=\''"height: 18px;\''"><td style=\''"width: 33.7887%; height: 18px; text-align: center;\''"><strong>Build Link</strong></td><td style=\''"width: 66.2113%; height: 18px; text-align: center;\''">'$notif_url/$notif_repo/actions/runs/$notif_runid'</td></tr><tr style=\''"height: 18px;\''"><td style=\''"width: 33.7887%; height: 18px; text-align: center;\''"><strong>Executed By</strong></td><td style=\''"width: 66.2113%; height: 18px; text-align: center;\''">'$notif_actor'</td></tr></tbody></table><p>&nbsp;</p>''"'
```

VARIABLE OUTPUT

```
"<h3><span style=\"text-decoration: underline;\"><strong><em>Build Execute Summary</em></strong></span></h3><p>&nbsp;</p><table style=\"border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; height: 162px;\" border=\"1\"><tbody><tr style=\"height: 18px;\"><td style=\"width: 33.7887%; height: 18px; text-align: center;\"><strong>Result</strong></td><td style=\"width: 66.2113%; height: 18px; text-align: center;\">$notif_result</td></tr><tr style=\"height: 18px;\"><td style=\"width: 33.7887%; height: 18px; text-align: center;\"><strong>Infra Type</strong></td><td style=\"width: 66.2113%; height: 18px; text-align: center;\">internal</td></tr><tr style=\"height: 18px;\"><td style=\"width: 33.7887%; text-align: center; height: 18px;\"><strong>Environment</strong></td><td style=\"width: 66.2113%; text-align: center; height: 18px;\">$environment</td></tr><tr style=\"height: 18px;\"><td style=\"width: 33.7887%; text-align: center; height: 18px;\"><strong>Application Name</strong></td><td style=\"width: 66.2113%; text-align: center; height: 18px;\">$application</td></tr><tr style=\"height: 18px;\"><td style=\"width: 33.7887%; height: 18px; text-align: center;\"><strong>Build Name</strong></td><td style=\"width: 66.2113%; height: 18px; text-align: center;\">$region-$application-$environment-$notif_runnum</td></tr><tr style=\"height: 18px;\"><td style=\"width: 33.7887%; height: 18px; text-align: center;\"><strong>Build Link</strong></td><td style=\"width: 66.2113%; height: 18px; text-align: center;\">$notif_url/$notif_repo/actions/runs/$notif_runid</td></tr><tr style=\"height: 18px;\"><td style=\"width: 33.7887%; height: 18px; text-align: center;\"><strong>Executed By</strong></td><td style=\"width: 66.2113%; height: 18px; text-align: center;\">$notif_actor</td></tr></tbody></table><p>&nbsp;</p>"
```

Now, I'm trying to use jq to read my JSON file and to insert the formatted variable above. I'm using the --raw-input option so the backslashes in the template variable will be accepted. However, I'm still getting the error below.

```
jq --raw-input --slurp --ascii-output --arg html $template '.Body.Html.Data = test' ses_message.json > ses_message.json
```

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
style=\"text-decoration:      
jq: 1 compile error
```

Is it a quoting problem? If yes, how to correct it?

Bash JQuery.

Comment: `--arg html "$template"` -- the quotes are not optional (literal quotes inside your data do not substitute for syntactic quotes in your code -- that goes the other way as well).

Comment: Also, you probably want `'.Body.Html.Data = $html'`

Comment: Thanks! That looks to have solved my problem. I'm getting a different error after applying your solution but i think my original issue is already resolved.

Comment: I suspect you want to take all the literal quoting out of your variable's contents -- let jq do the quoting.

Comment: (see https://ideone.com/skud9r mocking up the change I'm proposing there; btw, jq is not related to jquery -- two completely different things despite the confusingly similar names and resulting search-hit overlap)

Comment: Also see [Quotes - Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes), particularly the [When Should You Quote?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes#When_Should_You_Quote.3F) section.

Comment: I've tried using your proposed change for the variable but when I try applying it, im getting the error below.


TRIED COMMANDS:
[1] jq --arg html $template '.Body.Html.Data = $html' ses_message.json > temp.json
[2] jq --arg html $template '.Body | fromjson | .Html | fromjson | .Data = $html | tojson' ses_message.json > temp.json

ERROR:
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting QQSTRING_TEXT or QQSTRING_INTERP_START or QQSTRING_END (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
style="text-decoration:       
jq: 1 compile error

Comment: Your variable `template` contains spaces (around the word _Execute_).

Comment: If you try a new command, edit your question. In your comment, the command and the error message is virtually unreadable.  Since the question is already closed, you could ask a new question (this is perhaps faster than editing the current one and hoping that someone will reopen it).